# MSBuild - How to specify the associated PDB file for an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly

I'm referencing another .NET assembly using the `Reference` tag in my `.csproj` file. I'd like to be able to step into this assembly while debugging my app, which requires the `.pdb` file associated with it to be copied to the output directory. Unfortunately, the `.pdb` for it is not present in the same directory as the assembly, meaning that MSBuild doesn't pick up on it.

Is there any way to point MSBuild to the `.pdb`, so it can copy it to the output directory? (I suppose I could use a `Copy` task for this purpose to copy the `.pdb` to the same directory just before build, but that feels a bit hackish.)

**TL;DR** How to I specify the `.pdb` for a referenced assembly in MSBuild, if it's not in the same directory?

Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx

Comment: *which requires the .pdb file associated with it to be copied to the output directory* see Dmitry's link, this is not true. The orignal pdb file path is hardcoded into the dll and it's the first place where the debugger goes looking for it

Answer (score 0):

There is a repo on github called [msbuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild). I don't know how exaclty it relates with msbuild utility shipped with .net framework, but there is a [hint](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/c1459f5cbd36f2c33eafc8f4ff087f6ee84c3640/src/XMakeTasks/AssemblyDependency/ReferenceTable.cs#L866) about how related files can be found:

```
private void FindRelatedFiles
(
    Reference reference
)
{
    string baseName = reference.FullPathWithoutExtension;
    // Look for companion files like pdbs and xmls that ride along with 
    // assemblies.
    foreach (string companionExtension in _relatedFileExtensions)
    {
        string companionFile = baseName + companionExtension;
        if (_fileExists(companionFile))
        {
            reference.AddRelatedFileExtension(companionExtension);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

where `_relatedFileExtensions` is the array filled with [the extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/c1459f5cbd36f2c33eafc8f4ff087f6ee84c3640/src/XMakeTasks/AssemblyDependency/ResolveAssemblyReference.cs#L74):

```
private string[] _relatedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".pdb", ".xml", ".pri" };
```

So, as we can see, the `baseName` is the full path without extension of your thirdparty reference. So the related *.pdb must be in the same directory, if you want it be copied by **ResolveAssemblyReferences** target.

If you want to copy your thirdparty *.pdb file from another source, you have to deal with "hackish" solutions. One of them is to copy it in the AfterBuild target:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="PathToPdb" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"/> 
</Target>
```

Or you can mark the file as [content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="PathToPdb">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```